# Show that $\sigma_n^2$ is an unbiased estimator for $\sigma^2$

Tags: probability, statistics, expected-value, variance

Let $X_n$ be a sequence of i.i.d. random variables with $E(X_i)=\mu,Var(X_i)=\sigma^2$ and define $\mu_n:=\frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n X_i,\sigma_n^2:=\sum_{i=1}^n(X_i-\mu_n)^2.$

I have already shown that $Var(\mu_n)=\frac{\sigma^2}{n}$. Now to show that $\sigma_n^2$ is an unbiased estimator for $\sigma^2$ I need to show $E(\sigma_n^2)=\sigma^2$. What I have so far is:

$E(\sum_{i=1}^n(X_i-\mu_n)^2)=\sum_{i=1}^nE((X_i-\mu_n)^2)=\sum_{i=1}^nVar(X_i-\mu_n)-(E(X_i-\mu_n))^2=\sum_{i=1}^nVar(X_i)+Var(\mu_n)-\sum_{i=1}^nE((X_i-\mu_n)^2)=\sum_{i=1}^n \sigma^2+\sigma^2/n-\sum_{i=1}^nE((X_i-\mu_n)^2)=n\sigma^2+\sigma^2-E(\sum_{i=1}^n(X_i-\mu_n)^2)$

Here I have used the fact that the variance of the sum of two independent variables is the sum of the single variances, the product of expectations of independent variables is the expectation of the product and the sum of the expectations is the expectation of the sum.

Adding the identical sums on both sides togehter I get $2E(\sum_{i=1}^n(X_i-\mu_n)^2)=n\sigma^2+\sigma^2$. Dividing by $2$ unfortunately doesn't give me $\sigma^2$ due to the $n$ on the right side which makes me think that some of my conclusions were wrong.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Don't you need a factor of $1/(n-1)$ in front of your definition of $\sigma_n^2$?

Comment: Yes I think the definition was wrong. Still even with this factor I get $\sigma^2 \frac{n+1}{n}$

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but you seem to be treating $X_i$ and $\mu_n$ as independent, which they're not. This is because the particular sample $X_i$ forms part of the definition of $\mu_n$.

Comment: Oh ok I got that wrong!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define:
$$
\sigma_n^2 \;=\; \frac{1}{n-1}\sum_{i=1}^n{\left(X_i - \mu_n\right)}^2
$$
Then:
\begin{align}
E(\sigma_n^2) &\;=\; \frac{1}{n-1}\sum_{i=1}^n E\left[{\left(X_i - \mu_n\right)}^2\right]\\
&\;=\; \frac{1}{n-1}\sum_{i=1}^n E\left(X_i^2 - 2X_i\mu_n + \mu_n^2\right)\\
&\;=\; \frac{1}{n-1}\sum_{i=1}^n\Bigl[E(X_i^2) - 2 E(X_i\mu_n) + E(\mu_n^2)\Bigr]\qquad (1)
\end{align}
The three terms inside the sum are:
\begin{align}
\bullet\; E(X_i^2) &\;=\;\sigma^2 + \mu^2 
\end{align}
\begin{align}
\bullet\; E(X_i \mu_n) &\;=\;\frac{1}{n}E\left(X_i \sum_{j = 1}^n X_j\right)\\
&\;=\; \frac{1}{n}E\left(X_i^2 + \sum_{j\neq i} X_iX_j\right)\\
&\;=\; \frac{1}{n}\left[\sigma^2 + \mu^2 + (n-1)\mu^2\right]\\
&\;=\; \frac{\sigma^2}{n} + \mu^2
\end{align}
\begin{align}
\bullet\; E(\mu_n^2)
&\;=\;\frac{1}{n^2}E\left(\sum_{j=1}^n\sum_{k=1}^n X_j X_k\right)\\
&\;=\; \frac{1}{n^2}\left[\sum_{j=1}^nE(X_j^2) + \sum_{j=1}^n\sum_{k\neq j}E(X_j)E(X_k)\right]\\
&\;=\; \frac{1}{n^2}\left[n(\sigma^2 +\mu^2) + n(n-1)\mu^2\right]\\
&\;=\; \frac{\sigma^2}{n} +\mu^2
\end{align}

If you substitute these three expressions into (1) and simplify, you do indeed get $E(\sigma_n^2) = \sigma^2$.